# Charts don't show up when subreport is included in group header in pentaho reporting 3.9.1-GA

Tags: pentaho

There is an issue concerning in sub-reports.

I created a bar chart in report header. The sub report(banded) is placed in the Details of main report.  In  the sub report, the bar chart is placed in the group header. I imported the required parameters to the sub reports from the main report and also i have a sub query for the sub report.The expected output is to show an updated bar chart within each (inner) group of main report. However, the chart is only displayed in the last group occurence, although the chart area itself is allotted in every expected case. 
Can any one say me, what mistake i did.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting; I believe there was a bug very similar to this fixed in the last few months. Could you try the latest 3.9.X build and see if its still a problem?

The issue that was fixed was specific to charts in subreports not rendering.

Comment: b.t.w. its not clear where on ci the latest builds are, could be this one: http://ci.pentaho.com/view/Reporting/job/BRANCH_reporting-report-designer/  the on-reporting.com website only has v5.0 builds.

Comment: I couldn't get the projects from that link... Can you explain me what is in that link..

Comment: That link is a CI build of the report engine and designer source code. so it always reflects the latest build of whatever branch is there. Browse around the ci.pentaho.com site it should be there somewhere.

Comment: I got output sir.. Thank you sir

Comment: I got output.., I want to publish my report to pentaho BI server 4.8.0... but i couldn't publish my report... error is displaying

Comment: is this a different issue then?  what is the error?  So just to be clear the CI build did fix your original problem?

Comment: I download the TRUNK-SNAPSHOT version from "http://ci.pentaho.com/view/Reporting/job/BRANCH_reporting-report-designer/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/report-designer-assembly/dist/" .... and i run my issue report in this version.. I got my expected result..  i want to publish my report to pentaho BI server 4.8.0. but the error is displaying "Unable to publish your report"...  So now what can i do for that...

Comment: Ah ok; So if it works in PRD then you will also need to upgrade your reporting libraries on the BI Server too.  Google around to see how to do that.

Comment: Sir Can you please send me the link for upgrading libraries on BI server.,

Comment: pentaho-reporting*.jar